# Why Drupal 8 is adding a GET variable at the end of every css file and it shows as 404?

Tags: php, css, drupal, drupal-8

I've been breaking my head for the last few hours with no success. I've just received a Drupal 8 site to migrate and I've been dealing with the different issues successfully. Everything is already set-up. But, the css is not loading... I don't understand why, but it throws a 404 only when reading the CSS files. And when I compare the name of the file and the requested file, the only thing is a GET variable (?oe62rp) And the console result: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

To make myself clear, the css is named: "css_8NJTqUtfgfOeudX3OTMA0AD8Kc__DiYFotvyFNXb2mY.css", But the requested file is: "css_8NJTqUtfgfOeudX3OTMA0AD8Kc__DiYFotvyFNXb2mY.css **?oe62rp**"

Please help me, I've been digging internet the last few hours with no result and I'm desperate.

Thank you so much in advance, kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, after digging a little more, I found that I had do disable css aggregation via */admin/config/development/performance* Then everything ran properly... Also keep in mind that is very difficult to work with an IP... It's better and easier to set up a domain...

Thank you anyway :)